# vs2008 theme changed but nothing happens

Tags: visual-studio-2008, themes

I imported a new theme in VS 2008 and after I imported successfully my IDE has not changed, fonts and colors are the same as the older ones.

What's the problem? Anybody seen this issue? Any ideas?

Thanks.

My environment:
VS 2008 IDE
themes downloaded from here http://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian

Comment: Have you tried restarting your IDE?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!...I restarted my Computer but the result is same. maybe I should reinstall my vs2008...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure you are installing the text editor theme properly. The proper steps are exactly as follows:

1. Tools > Import and Export Settings
2. Choose the "Import selected environment settings" option
3. Choose the "No, just import new settings, overwriting my current settings" option
4. Click the "Browse..." button and then select the theme file you downloaded
5. Choose "Finish" on the "Choose Settings to Import" screen

Comment: Thanks a lot. 

It's maybe my IDE installation problem.  I should reinstall VS 2008.